# CakePHP view variable scope issue

Tags: cakephp, view, global-variables

I have these lines in my view file

```
////////////////////////////

$a = 5;
showme()

showme()
{
 global $a;
 echo $a;
}

////////////////////////////////
```

Problem:  $a is not accessible in showme() function.

I have no choice to pass `$a` as argument and no choice to move function from view. And it should be accessible in function through `global` keyword only.

I can change the way of declaration to `$a`.

Comment: Is it so bad to pass a variable to the function?  Globals are generally a bad idea, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the semi-colon to end the later statement:

```
$a = 5;
showme()
```

Change to:

```
$a = 5;
showme();
```

Your code seems to be ok, it should work, not sure but you may try this if you are inside a class:

```
$a = 5;
$this->showme();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $a is actually not defined in the global scope , but within the view template. Therefore,

```
global $a;
```

is not working as you expect it.

I am not sure if this will work , but you can at least try it:

```
$GLOBALS['a'] = 5;

function showme(){
   echo $GLOBALS['a'];
}
```